# Direction between two points

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I need show direction between two points. First point - begin of the street, second point - end. How I can get latitude and longitude of the first and last houses in the street if I know only streetname?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible without knowledge of the house numbers.

See the docs for the [Directions API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/) to see what is possible.